# Show that $C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is complete.

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I need to show that $C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is complete.

$C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^{2})$ are continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\;d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left\Vert f(x)-g(x)\right\Vert _{2}\;$ where $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{2}$ is the standard euclidean distance over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

My problem is, is that I don't know how to even approach this. I know that it is sufficient to show that for each Cauchy sequence we can find a convergent sub-sequence, but it seems too abstract to follow that path.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outline of proof:**

Let $(f_n)$ be Cauchy in $X=C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^2).$ Then $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for each $x\in[0,1].$ Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete, it follows that $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent, to say $f.$

Now show that $f$ is continuous and $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

**Edit:** Let $\epsilon >0,$ then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(f_n,f_m)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n,m\geq N.$ Now for each $x,f_n(x) \to f(x),$ so choose $n_x\geq N$ such that $$\|f_{n_x}(x)-f(x)\|_2<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ We have \begin{align*}\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|_2&\leq\|f_n(x)-f_{n_x}(x)\|_2+\|f_{n_x}-f(x)\|_2\\&< d(f_n,f_{n_x})+\frac{\epsilon}2\\&<\epsilon\end{align*} for all $n\geq N,x \in [0,1].$ This implies $d(f_n,f)\leq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ and hence $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

How can I show in a formal way that (fn)→f  uniformly?
I can tell by sight that the distance meassured isn't dependant on a specific $x_0$

Comment: @vpam I have edited my answer to include the proof.

Comment: Don't you need to take $sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left\Vert f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right\Vert_2 $ tho?

Comment: @vpam I did. Since $\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|_2<\epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1],$ the inequality with $\leq$ holds for supremum. It is important here to note that $N$ doesn't depend on $x.$

Comment: So $n_x$ holds for all $x$?

Comment: @vpam For every $x,$ we can find $n_x \geq N.$ The choice of $n_x$ depend on $x$ but that doesn't matter to us. What we needed was for $N$ to be independent of $x,$ which it is. The point is for every $x,$ you can find a "middle" function in the sequence which makes $f_n(x)$ closer to $f(x).$ Basically no matter what $x$ you choose, you end up with $\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|_2 < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ (independent of your choice of $x$) which is crucial for uniform convergence.